# Why does the order of how we specify the variables in a '==' comparison matter?

Tags: drools

What i noticed is that there is a big performance difference by just changing the order of the variables that are compared with the '==' operator. For example $variable == variable is considerably slower than variable == $variable.
Why is this so and are there similar cases like this one?

By the way i am using a version of OptaPlanner from GitHub downloaded from GitHub that uses the "7.0.0-SNAPSHOT" Drools version.

This is the case in all the rules that do a cross product where i try to match variables from one pattern in another. For example:

```
rule "Example"
   when
       Class1(... , $var : var)
       Class2($var == var, ...)
   then
end
```

So when i changed the expression $var == var to var == $var immediately i could spot the difference.

When it comes to benchmarking at first i just compared this in one rule that i was focused on, so i only did this type of change in the expressions there(the other rules were deleted).
Afterwards i applied this to all the rules.

Comment: This may depend on the Drools version: which is it? Also, code of the rule and class for demonstrating the effect, and how you benchmarked it would be necessary.

Comment: I edited the question where i explain which Drools version i use, where does this occur in the rules and how i did the benchmarks.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, Jordan. [Issue created.](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-1519)

Comment: No problem Geoffrey i would be more than happy if issues like this are discovered and resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what happens is that

```
Class1(... , $var : var)
Class2(var == $var, ...)
```

produces a network where all Class1 facts are taken, and then the Cartesian product with all Class2 facts with identical `var` field is created.

In contrast,

```
Class1(... , $var : var)
Class2($var == var, ...)
```

"rewritten" by the compiler as

```
Class1(... , $var : var)
$c2: Class2(...)
eval( $var == $c2.var )
```

creates the Cartesian product of all Class1 facts and all (!) Class2 facts and only thereafter filters all where the eval is false.

The traditional syntax (Drools 5 and earlier) forced you to have the field name on the left-hand side; only later on (late 5.x, 6.x), any logical expression was permitted.

After speaking to s.o. from the Drools team, a more accurate description might be this:- It is likely that where an attribute is compared to something else an optimization is triggered. Someone from the Drools team will take a look and possibly improve it by checking also the reversed expression.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation was really helpful.

Comment: We created an issue to investigate if [Drools can just do the fast way all the time](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-1519), regardless of how the rule is written.