# Drools query not scaling well

Tags: drools

I am using Drools to do the score calculation in my OptaPlanner project and after I started to use queries to retrieve logical facts from the working memory to Java I realized that as the input size increased the queries took more time to finish (they did not scale well).

The logical facts that I’m retrieving contain accumulates from a bunch of constraints and I’m using them in the Java part of the application, the point is to reuse what drools has already calculated and retrieve these values in O(1) time.

**Note: The version of Drools and OptaPlanner that I’m using is 7.0.0-SNAPSHOT.**

### Replicating the problem with a simple Drools app

To present the scaling issue that I found out I simplified things and created a separate simple drools project which only contains one main class to execute the application and two other classes intended for the drools facts. This also obviously avoids the overhead that is added by OptaPlanner.

Like I mentioned in this simple project there are two classes that are intended for the facts, **Employee** which has a property "id" in it and **TotalHours** which has "employee" and "totalHours" as properties.

```
public class Employee {
    public int id;
}

public class TotalHours {
    public Employee employee;
    public int totalHours;
}
```

The query in this project is matching an employee that is passed in as a parameter in the call with the employee part of a TotalHours object. Note that for a given employee there can be a maximum of one TotalHours objects (either zero or one).

```
query "get TotalHours for Employee"  (Employee e)
   totalHours : TotalHours(employee == e)
end
```

The scaling issue is present no matter am I creating the TotalHours objects in the Java part and insert them in the working memory together with the Employee objects or write a rule that based on the Employee objects will create logical facts. Like I mentioned previously the facts in my OptaPlanner project the facts that are retrieved by the query are logical facts.

So obviously the query is not scaling like for example when a rule tries to match two patterns with their common property, like in the case below. Even in the case where the relationship between Employee and TotalHours is 1:N meaning that an employee can match in multiple TotalHours objects the application would roughly need the same amount of time to execute the rule no matter that the employee size is growing. It will scale well because of hashing.

```
rule "Match Employee and TotalHours"
    when
        $employee : Employee()
        TotalHours(employee == $employee)
    then
end
```

### Performance measurement

I’m doing two types of tests to measure the scalability of the simple drools application. In both cases depending on the test size N Employee and TotalHours objects are created, inserted in the working memory and “fireAllRules” is called. Then in:

Test 1 – The speed of the query is tested out as N is increased

1. The query is called 1000 times for employees selected on random
2. The time taken to finish these 1000 queries in the different sizes of N is measured

   ```
   double totalTime = 0L;
   for (int i = 0; i < testSize; i++) {
       int randomIndex = random.nextInt(employees.size());
       Employee employee = employees.get(randomIndex);
       long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
       QueryResults queryResults = kSession.getQueryResults("get TotalHours for Employee", employee);
       long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
       TotalHours totalHours = (TotalHours) queryResults.iterator().next().get("totalHours");
       totalTime += (endTime - startTime);
   }
   ```

Test 2 – The speed of the “Match Employee and TotalHours” rule is tested out as N is increased

1. The property “totalHours” in TotalHours is updated and fireAllRules is called 1000 times
2. The time taken to update the variable and execute in the different sizes of N is measured

   ```
   double totalTime = 0L;
   for (int i = 0; i < testSize; i++) {
       int randomIndex = random.nextInt(totalHoursList.size());
       TotalHours totalHours = totalHoursList.get(randomIndex);
       int randomTotalHours = random.nextInt(100000);
       long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
       totalHours.setTotalHours(randomTotalHours);
       FactHandle factHandle = kSession.getFactHandle(totalHours);
       kSession.update(factHandle, totalHours);
       kSession.fireAllRules();
       long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
       totalTime += (endTime - startTime);
   }
   ```

I have measured with 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000 and 500000 Employee and TotalHours objects inserted into the working memory.
In the results below we can see the average time taken (in milliseconds) to finish the query or execute the rule (average from the 1000 random trials).

**The steady increase in the average time taken to execute the query can be seen as the number of employees is increased whereas we can see that the rule that is matching the Employee to the TotalHours is working incrementally based on the results.**
[image: Results]

The screenshot below taken from a Java Mission Control Flight Recording reveals where most of the time is spent and as we can see 99.63% of the time is spent inside the method "org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakJoinNode.doLeftInserts".
[image: Call Tree from Flight Recording on version 7.0.0-SNAPSHOT]

Btw I made sure that the garbage collection does not make a distraction in these tests and I simply set the initial and max heap size to 6GB where the biggest test done here (500000 employees) needs around 700MB to run.
[image: CPU and memory usage]

### The issue still exists on the latest version of Drools (7.22.0.Final at this point)

I was curious to see is this issue taken care of in the newest version of Drools and based on the results that I've got it is still behaving in the same manner, it is still not scaling well. What I did was downloading the newest version of Drools (which at this point is 7.22.0.Final) and doing the same query test mentioned above.

We can see the results from the two versions side by side. Don't be deceived by the small increase in average time taken in the new version because there was more overhead on my computer when running the tests.
[image: Results from query test 7.0.0-SNAPSHOT vs 7.22.0.Final]

Also based on this screenshot taken from a Java Mission Control Flight Recording the hot spot still is the "org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakJoinNode.doLeftInserts" even though the stack looks slightly different.
[image: Call Tree from Flight Recording on version 7.22.0.Final]

**All things aside I’m searching for an effective O(1) way of retrieving what Drools has already calculated and being able to use that information in the Java side of the application.**

Comment: You're using Drools 7.0.0-SNAPSHOT? I only ask because 7.0.0.Final was *released* in May 2017, so I have no idea what's even in that particular snapshot version.

Comment: I'm using this version because I still did not had the chance to update to the newest version, I guess the simplest thing to do in order to see does the newest version have the same issue is to download it and try the same test on it.

Comment: Yeah 7.22.0 should be compatible based on what you've posted above.

Comment: Did you post to the google groups for drools on this?

Comment: I don't know drools very well (or at all), but I'm wondering why, if "Note that for a given employee there can be a maximum of one TotalHours objects (either zero or one).", then can you put total hours as a property of Employee? It looks like even though you have only one `TotalHours` it is being fetched as a join.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I was curious and I downloaded the newest version of Drools and did the same test on it and as described above the problem is still there.

Comment: @K.Nicholas I know that I can simply set the totalHours property be part of the Employee and I guess just simply do a "$employee.setTotalHours()" in the "then" part of a rule (avoiding update or modify in order to not re-trigger any rules, not sure if it is fully valid) and then through the employee object in Java access it, but the main point that I'm making here is that Drools has an obvious scaling issue in a somewhat trivial situation. I'm also searching for an alternative way to do it, the query seemed like the most legit way to do it, doing a set in the then part seems more like a hack.

Comment: I can't comment further without more experience with drools. I don't think an version update will fix the problem since I doubt the PhreakJoinNode class was changed. Never a bad idea to update though.

Comment: There's 2 years' worth of changes in the rest of the code base that you may as well pull in just in case it was related. Upon reviewing the Git repo there were changes in PhreakJoinNode during 7.0.0 development, so depending on the age of that snapshot they may not have been present. Also it makes sense you'd spend your time here since it appears this is a tree-like data structure, so as you shove more and more information into it, it will take longer and longer to traverse it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, I created a JIRA https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-4146 so that the developers working on the project can have a chance to review it and decide what they would do. I just want to make sure that something important is not missed like for example in this case that I found previously https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43282665/why-does-the-order-of-how-we-specify-the-variables-in-a-comparison-matter where var == $var is not the same as $var == var in terms of performance.